# Why gorm order pagenate got empty result?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have 2 tables, users and tasks, I want get users by order with tasks rows (number of tasks each user have ), then return the result of users by amount order.

Here is what I got:

```
err := DB.Table("users").
        Select("users.*, count(tasks.*) as tasks_quantity").
        Joins("JOIN tasks ON tasks.user_addr = users.user_addr").
        Group("users.user_addr, users.id").
        Order("tasks_quantity").Offset(perPage * pageNum).Limit(perPage).Find(&allUsers).
        Error
```

Now the result always empty.

What did I wrong? How should I achieve my goal correctly?

(I think my order is also wrong, I need descending order of tasks num)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `group by` some sql require explisitly enumerate fields that you want to grouping. I suppose that your table `users` has more fields than just `id, user_addr` if it is true you have to add explicilty it to `group by` or just change your select to fields which you want to display, for example try something like this.

```
err := DB.Table("users").
        Select("users.user_addr, users.id, count(tasks.*) as tasks_quantity").
        Joins("JOIN tasks ON tasks.user_addr = users.user_addr").
        Group("users.user_addr, users.id").
        Order("tasks_quantity DESC").Offset(perPage * pageNum).Limit(perPage).Find(&allUsers).
        Error
```

p.s. For descending order just add `DESC` operator after your field in `Order`

Comment: thank u Sir! I'll try it tonight, but I have one question: why Select users.user_addr must align with Group, I have more feilds i users, will I get all of them in &allUsers? (I have user_nick_name, user_gender etc)

Comment: @NicholasJela You have to align all fields that you want to `SELECT` with `Group` it is requirement for some databases (postgresql for example). If you want to get `user_nick_name` and `user_gender `  and others you must add it to `Select` and `Group`

Comment: thanks. But i have too many feilds, 15+ of fileds. need I write it one by one in query string? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @NicholasJela Yes, just use subquery and `where` instead of `Joins`, try something like this

`err := DB.Table("users").Where("user_addr IN (SELECT t.user_addr  FROM tasks AS t GROUP BY user_addr ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC OFFSET (?::int) * (?::int) LIMIT ?::int )", perPage, pageNum, perPage).Find(&allUsers).Error`


result be the same if `user_addr` is unique in `users` table

Comment: I tried this solution: `err := DB.Table("users").
  Select("users.user_addr, users.id, count(tasks.*) as tasks_quantity").
  Joins("JOIN tasks ON tasks.user_addr = users.user_addr").
  Group("users.user_addr, users.id").
  Order("tasks_quantity DESC").Offset(perPage * pageNum).Limit(perPage).Find(&allUsers).
  Error` and it returns [] empty result as well

Comment: As well as `err := DB.Table("users").Where("user_addr IN (SELECT t.user_addr  FROM tasks AS t GROUP BY user_addr ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC OFFSET (?::int) * (?::int) LIMIT ?::int )", perPage, pageNum, perPage).Find(&allUsers).Error`. Do u know why?

Comment: I found this can return result (remove pagenating): `err := DB.Table("users").
  Select("users.*, count(tasks.*) as tasks_quantity").
  Joins("JOIN tasks ON tasks.user_addr = users.user_addr").
  Group("users.user_addr, users.id").
  Order("tasks_quantity DESC").
  Scan(&allUsers).
  Error` But this will return all result which is big (1000+ records), what should I do?

Comment: Try to debug you sql `DB.LogMode(true)` and see what is wrong is with your query builder. Check your params `perPage & pageNum`